# How to do multiple commands inside a forfiles batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop

We want to create a batch script that runs a command for each of our .xml files. The command should run for every file that does NOT end with **_m**. We try to go through each file with forfiles, but we dont know how to use **do** togheter with it.

This is our current not working script, where we try to go through every file. Identify the filename, and substring it to not run the command if it ends with **_m**.

```
forfiles /p /source /m *.xml do (

set "filename=@fname"
set "extension=_m.xml"
set "extended=%filename%extension"


IF NOT %filename:~-2%=="_m"(
    ssoadm import-entity --cot something--realm something--spec saml2 -m @file -x %extended --adminid something--password-file password --debug
)
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Just use the built-in `for` command instead of the external `forfiles` command, then you'll be able to use `do`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (
 'dir /b /a-d *.xml^|findstr /v /e /i /L "_m.xml" '
) do (
   ssoadm import-entity --cot something--realm something--spec saml2 -m "%%a" -x %extended --adminid something--password-file password --debug
)
```

for each entry in a `dir` in `/b` basic form (names only) `/a-d` without directorynames; finding names which `/v` do not `/e` end `/i` case-insensitive `/L` literally "-m.xml", assign the complete name found to `%%a`

No idea what `ssoadm` does, but

`%%~na` will yield the basename of the file, and `%%~xa` the extension.

Your code might work, but you'd need to invoke `delayed expansion` (search SO) and modify the code to suit delayedexpansion methodology (as documented many, many times on SO)

---

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (
 'dir /b /a-d *.xml^|findstr /v /e /i /L "_m.xml" '
) do (
   echo(%%~na
   echo(%%~xa
   echo(%%~nxa
   echo(%%a
   echo(%%a %%~na_M%%~xa
)
```

...pick the parts/constants as you will and put them together meccano-style.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I still dont get it quite how I want.


Say if I have four files: file1.xml, file1_m.xml, file2.xml and file2_m.xml and I need to use the pairs in each of the commands. How do I do that? This is the commands I want to run:

 `somecommand -x file1.xml -m file1_m.xml` and 
 `somecommand -x file2.xml -m file2_m.xml`